# Sub group of group in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
dealer  desktop tablet
A       1       0
A       1       0
B       0       1
C       0       0
A       0       1
A       1       0
C       0       1
C       0       0
C       0       0
B       0       1
B       0       0
B       0       0
A       0       0
```

Not very good at SQL

What I want to do here is

1. Group by dealer
2. Get the count of desktop, laptop(`when desktop = 0 and tablet = 0`) and tablet

```
SELECT dealer, COUNT(*) FROM table
GROUP BY dealer
```

got me the count of dealers, but based on the criteria, I don't know how to get it.

What I expect is a row of counts.

`dealer | laptop | desktop | tablet`

Comment: Generally you would use ***conditional aggregation*** where `COUNT()` is implemented through `SUM()`.  In MySQL you can do it with directly with `COUNT(<boolean condition>)` since MySQL treats `true` as `1` and `false` as `0`.

Comment: @PM77-1 you mean `SUM(<boolean condition>)`; COUNT counts non-nulls, so will count even false

Comment: @ysth - You are right.

Comment: Thanks for the help @PM77-1 and ysth. Learned something today :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
    select dealer, 
       COALESCE(SUM(case when desktop = 0 and tablet = 0 then 1 end),0) as laptop,
       COALESCE(SUM(case when desktop = 1 then 1 end),0) as desktop,
       COALESCE(SUM(case when tablet = 1 then 1 end),0) as tablet
from test
group by dealer;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=47d3d7761784bda3b94413f6603e06f7

Comment: This is perfect, love the solution it's clean. I needed to add `else 0` as some of my results were `NULL`. Learned something new today. Thank you.

Comment: note than SUM will return null if there are no such rows, so you probably want `COALESCE( SUM(...), 0)` or add `else 0` to your cases

Comment: @DhavalJardosh updated, you need COALESCE as ysth mentioned

Answer (score 1):

select dealer,
sum(desktop) as desktop,
sum(tablet) as tablet,
sum(

First you have to create another column for laptop. i would just use a case when statement, google it for further details.

(
select *,
case (when desktop + tablet = '0' then '1'
else '0'
end) as laptop
from ____
)

Then, you can call back different sums and group by dealer!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).